# Will This Mini PCI-E Half Length Card Fit Into Any of These Slots?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, wireless-card

Will this 802.11 Wireless b/g/n PCI-E Mini card (Interface type: PCI-e half-length mini card)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Kek.jpg]

fit any of the slots on this motherboard?
[Newegg - GIGABYTE GA-Z77-HD3](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128582)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The board needs to have a Mini PCI-e slot, which is found predominantly on 8-series chipset boards and some small form factor 7-series boards.

Comment: This... Mini PCIe and PCIe are totally different physically. I found that out the hard way myself.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. I was thinking of switching that card over to this motherboard, because I am having the current board that it is fitted onto replaced by it.I suppose this means I actually need to find a wireless card that says PCI-E x1?

Comment: It does not need to say `x1`. x4, x8 and x16 will also work. Tough no wireless card needs that much bandwidth. But any card should work fine in one of your x1 slots or the other x16 slot. Just do not get PCI, miniPCI, or mini PCI-e. Just plain PCI-e.